# Order of Elements of the Generating set???

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The following example is just to clarify the idea in non-abelian case

The dihedral group has the following presentation $$D_{2i}=\left<s,r/s^2=r^i=e,sr=r^{-1}s \right>$$
Order of $D_{2i}$ is $2i$ , if we take $S=\{s,r\}$ and $H=\{s,sr\}$, then  $D_{2i}=\left<S \right>=\left<H\right>$, but sum order of element of $S$ is 2+i and of $H$ is 4. From this we deduce that there is no relation between the order of the non-abelian group and the orders of elements in minimal generating set.

My question is there any relation between the order of **abelian** group and the order of elements in its minimal generating sets?

I guess the following is true $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ is a minimal generating set of abelian group $G$ then $\Pi_{i=1}^k order(s_i) \geq order(G)$.

Is this equation is true, and is there any other relations?

Please, any help will be useful.

Comment: I don't think this is true. For instance, take $G=(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}})\oplus(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}})\oplus(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}})$. This group can be generated by $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ However, the sum of the orders of the generators is 6, while the order of the group is 8.

Comment: Sorry i mean multiplication instead of addition that is $\Pi_{i=1}^k order(s_i) \geq order(G)$.